# Every time I type a comment in emacs, tramp freezes it

Tags: emacs, comments, freeze, tramp

Every time I type a comment in emacs, tramp freezes it.

it says:`Tramp: waiting for prompts from remote shell`

This happens for any file I open.  It freezes for a minute whenever I type `/`, and repeats for all characters typed until whitespace.

I found a few other questions like this, but they all seemed to be asked by people who use tramp.  I do not use tramp.  Had it not been freezing emacs, I would not have known what it is.

Can anyone tell me how to make it stop?

[.emacs](http://pastebin.com/smXa16bs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it happen in every file?  Only for octave related files?

Have you tried with "emacs -Q"?.  If you are free of the problem with "emacs -Q", then check with "emacs -q", if not, post your emacs version and OS.

If with "emacs -q" you are free of the problem, the problem is in your .emacs.  Your .emacs is tiny, so a binary search of what is the offending part should be quick.

Answer (score 2):

By default, auto-complete suggests file names when you type //, and this invokes tramp to get the file name list. To turn of this behaviour, make sure ac-source-filename is not in your ac-sources list. An easy way to do this globally is to edit your auto-complete-config.el to comment out the line

```
(add-hook 'auto-complete-mode-hook 'ac-common-setup)
```